# preg_match problem

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm trying to use preg_match to find php code statements in template files so I can convert them to a different syntax (smarty).

Executing the following example isn't producing any matches, can someone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

```
$test = '<?=$test?>';
preg_match( '/<?=$([a-z]+)?>/', $test, $code );
```

Comment: Please stop writing tags in titles, and titles should be more descriptive than "<function name> problem"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_match( '/<\?=\$([a-z]+)\?>/i', $test, $code );
```

Also you can safely omit the parenthesis there

```
preg_match( '/<\?=\$[a-z]+\?>/i', $test, $code );
```

Comment: there was no downvote? I'm not a registered user so I can't upvote or downvote, just select answers which I just did

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape special chars, that are used in regular expressions. You can use preg_quote() for this purpose